# React filtering data error: this.props.updateFilter is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a filter for an image list that works as you type and getting the above error. I think it's to do with the way I've mapped the data I'm importing, but can't figure it out. I'm still learning React.

```
var Filters = React.createClass({
  handleFilterChange: function() {
    var value = this.refs.filterInput.getDOMNode().value;
    this.props.updateFilter(value);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <input type="text" ref="filterInput" onChange={this.handleFilterChange} placeholder="Filter" />;
  }
});

/** @jsx React.DOM */
var ListItem = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li className="col-lg-3" style={listStyle}>
                <h2>{this.props.filename}</h2>
                <p><img className="img-thumbnail" src={this.props.photoLink}/></p>
                <p>
                    <small>Camera model: <strong>{this.props.model}</strong></small><br/>
                    <small>Camera make: <strong>{this.props.make}</strong></small>
                </p>
            </li>
        )
    }
});


var ListContainer = React.createClass({
    loadNotificationsFromServer: function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { 
          this.setState({data: this.state.data.concat([data])});                
          clearInterval(this.interval);         
        }.bind(this)
      });
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: [],
            nameFilter: ''
        };            
    }, 

    componentWillMount: function() {
      this.loadNotificationsFromServer();
      this.interval = setInterval(this.loadNotificationsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
    }, 

    render: function() {
        if (this.state.data) {         
            return (
                <div>
                    {this._hasData()}
                </div>
            )          
        } else {   
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } return false
    },

    _handleFilterUpdate: function(filterValue) {
        this.setState({
            nameFilter: filterValue
        });
    },    
    _hasData: function() {

        var data = this.state.data.map(function(item) {
            return item.works.work; 
        });
        if (data.length > 0) {                
            var imageDetails = _.map(data[0], function(result, n, key){
                var image = _(result.urls.url).find({'_type': 'small'});

                return {
                    id: result.id,
                    filename: result.filename,
                    _type: image ? image._type : null,
                    url: image ? image.__text : null,
                    model: result.exif.model,
                    make: result.exif.make
                };
            }, []);              
            var listItems = imageDetails.map(function(result, index){
                return <ListItem key={index} 
                        filename={result.filename} 
                        photoLink={result.url} 
                        model={result.model} 
                        make={result.make}  />
            })
            return listItems
        } else return false
    }
});

// INITIALISE PAGE
var imageList= React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      /* component composition == function componsition */
      return (
        <div>       
            <Filters updateFilter={this._handleFilterUpdate} />
            <ListContainer url="/scripts/works.json" pollInterval={2000}/>          
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

module.exports = imageList;
```

Comment: I don't see you define `_handleFilterUpdate` in your `imageList`. You seems to define that in `ListContainer`, but `ListContainer ` and `Filters`  are both child component of `imageList`. And `ListContainer` didn't use it at all, try move that with the related states to `ImageList`, or read [Thinking in react](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) to have a better way to put that function.

Comment: as @fuyushimoya said...